# Magento SOAP v1 filters not filtering (Python Suds)

Tags: python, api, magento, soap, suds

**updated below**

Does anybody have an example of proper XML for the Magento SOAP v1 API to do something along the lines of the following?

```
client.call(session_token,'sales_order.list', {'filters':{'order_id':{'eq':12}}})
```

This is an example of the python suds call that is not working for me. Really, any example XML that filters sales_order.list, catalog_product.list, or customer.list would do. I have it working for the XMLRPC version already, but with python's SUDS and the SOAP v1 API, no matter what the filter, I get the entire list unfiltered as response. Here's what the XML currently looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns4="urn:Magento" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<ns1:Body>
<ns4:call>
<sessionId xsi:type="ns2:string">6634e1bd1004557677222fd81e809884</sessionId>
<resourcePath xsi:type="ns2:string">sales_order.list</resourcePath>
<args xsi:type="ns0:args">
<filters xsi:type="ns2:filters">
<order_id xsi:type="ns2:order_id">
<eq xsi:type="ns2:string">7</eq>
</order_id>
</filters>
</args>
</ns4:call>
</ns1:Body>
```

Of course I've already tried a million other variations on the above. I'm just wondering if my calls are correct and I've got a bad schema, or if the soap server's wonky, or what. Thus, if anyone has some proven correct XML to try to emulate, it'd help a lot.

Thanks!

**update:**

as per the first answer I've received so far, I've actually tried that format for filters already. The documentation for the Magento API is, as we know, varied, conflicting, and incomplete. here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns4="urn:Magento" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<ns1:Body>
<ns4:call>
<sessionId xsi:type="ns2:string">93c7aaab38adaab5db732b211e5b</sessionId>
<resourcePath xsi:type="ns2:string">sales_order.list</resourcePath>
<args xsi:type="ns0:args">
<filter xsi:type="ns2:filter">
<value xsi:type="ns2:string">123</value>
<key xsi:type="ns2:string">order_id</key>
</filter>
</args>
</ns4:call>
</ns1:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

or possibly:

```
<ns1:Body>
<ns4:call>
<sessionId xsi:type="ns2:string">93c74cb7ef0baaaaab5db732b211e5b</sessionId>
<resourcePath xsi:type="ns2:string">sales_order.list</resourcePath>
<args xsi:type="ns0:args">
<filter xsi:type="ns2:filter">
<value xsi:type="ns2:value">
<value xsi:type="ns2:string">123</value>
<key xsi:type="ns2:string">eq</key>
</value>
<key xsi:type="ns2:string">order_id</key>
</filter>
</args>
</ns4:call>
</ns1:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

which looks like this:

```
{'filter':[{'key':'order_id','value':{'key':'eq','value':'123'}}]}
```

in python.

And those still return all orders (eventually...). So, as I mentioned, if anybody can actually give me some XML to emulate, it might be more useful. I'm likely going to root through the Magento source tomorrow and solve my own problem.

Comment: did you ever get XML? I'm running against the same issue.  And heaps of PHP examples, which sort of defeats the point of an API eh :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I had to brush off (and learn) my PHP, but I have the answer here if any other poor saps come along and want to use SUDS (or python in general) with Magento.

this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:Magento" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:call><sessionId xsi:type="xsd:string">bc11488aaae84c841ac237ea7f24ef</sessionId>
<resourcePath xsi:type="xsd:string">sales_order.list</resourcePath>
<args SOAP-ENC:arrayType="ns2:Map[1]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">
<item xsi:type="ns2:Map">
<item>
<key xsi:type="xsd:string">order_id</key>
<value xsi:type="ns2:Map">
<item>
<key xsi:type="xsd:string">from</key>
<value xsi:type="xsd:string">11</value>
</item>
<item>
<key xsi:type="xsd:string">to</key>
<value xsi:type="xsd:string">12</value>
</item>
</value>
</item>
</item>
</args>
</ns1:call>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

is created by this php:

```
#! /usr/bin/php5
<?php
$client = new SoapClient('http://ip.ip.ip.ip/magento/index.php/api/?wsdl', array('trace'=>TRUE));
$session = $client->login('username', 'password');
$params = array(array(
        'order_id' =>
          array(
            'from' => '10',
            'to' => '12')));



$result = $client->call($session, 'sales_order.list', $params);
$resultXML = $client->__getLastRequest();
print($resultXML);
?>
```

Of course, it turns out that there are also sorts of SOAP-related encoding issues around Magento's particular implementation of the protocol - it seems as tho it's designed to work with the PHP Soap client, but not really with anything else. But this XML dump did allow me to hack around and get the SUDS connection off the ground - send me a message if you're curious. Oh, and a hat tip to @alanstorm.

Comment: Yes, the serialization of Hash and Array uses `ns2:Map` and `SOAP-ENC:Array` respectively, which are caused by PHP `SoapServer`.  Using traditional XML elements will get you a `stdObject` from PHP `SoapServer` in Magento instead of an associative array.

Comment: +1 Omg.. thats awesome. I was applying filter to `customer.list`. And solution provided here worked for me for api v1. I just modified field name. thanks :)

Comment: sending a message isn't a thing on stackoverflow :) Could you update your answer to share the python equivalent if possible ? I'm going nuts over here :/

Answer (score 1):

**You write the wrong format array input for the filter.**

I think, if this is the solution for php.

```
$params = array(array(
            'filter' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'status',
                    'value' => 'pending'
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'created_at',
                    'value' => '2001-11-25 12:12:07',
                )
            ),
            'complex_filter' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'order_id',
                    'value' => array(
                        'key' => 'in',
                        'value' => '12,23'
                    ),
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'protect_code',
                    'value' => array(
                        'key' => 'eq',
                        'value' => 'ebb2a0'
                    ),
                ),
            )
        ));

$result = $client->__call('salesOrderList', $params);
```

You can just equalize it with python.

Comment: updated my question to reflect this answer. also, is this not the V2 API?

Comment: @EliAlbert Your's is SOAP API V2, but the parameter would be the same because the V2 extends V1 API classes (on php).

Comment: did you mean to say "yours is SOAP API V1"? In fact I've found that a lot of the filter parameters for V2 do _not_ apply to V1 - for instance, the "in" operator was not working in my tests.

Comment: Yes you're right!! sorry for the typo. nice answer @EliAlbert

Comment: question is in python and XML.  Answer is in a different language.  Handy that.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is about v1 of the API, but if you use v2 you can do this:

PHP:

```
$complexFilter = array(
    'complex_filter' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'type',
            'value' => array('key' => 'in', 'value' => 'simple,configurable')
        )
    )
);
$result = $client->catalogProductList($session, $complexFilter);
```

Python equivalent:

```
complex_filter = [{'complex_filter': [{
    'key': 'type',
    'value': [{
        'key': 'in',
        'value': 'simple,configurable'}]
    }]
}]
client.service.catalogProductList(session, complex_filter)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am trying the Python equivalent and keep getting a

```
ValidationError: Missing element for Any
```

However I pass the filter to the client.service method